# Visual Studio C++ 2019, broken undetailed Intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I'm just starting off with C++, setting up an environment in Visual Studio 2019. As I got used to coding in C# with intellisense, I thought it'd work the same way with C++, however it seems to be broken for me.[image]
as you can see, it doesn't provide detailed information about methods (or anything at all) like it does with C#. In fact, it doesn't even display all of the overloads.
I don't even know if it's supposed to be like that or if its a problem on my end...

Comment: If you begin the parens as if to begin the call you will be shown overloads.

Comment: Also, if there are comments preceding the function, which standard library functions such as `std::string::append` tend not to provide, those will be displayed as documentation. Try it with your own functions.

Comment: Well as C++ is much harder and slower to parse, IntelliSense will effectively not be as good as with C#. In particular, if you have large project, do modification with major impact or have a not very powerful computer, it only make things worst. Also Microsoft have put much more effort on C# than C++. Tools and integration are much better in C#. And mixing both type of project is even worst.

Comment: By the way, you should report your problems to Microsoft. If enough people complains about something, they might understand that it is consider important by many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as you can see, it doesn't provide detailed information about methods

It doesn't appear to be broken, c++ intellisense with Visual Studio just doesn't offer the documentation style descriptions that C# may. Though you can provide you own descriptions for methods by adding a comment just before their declaration and it should appear where you want in intellisense.

> (or anything at all)

c++ intellisense does give all of the method names and method declarations for the class, which isn't nothing and can be useful when you know generally what kind of method you need but don't know the specific method name, ( ex. .size() vs .count() vs .length() ) but I understand your frustration as I went from C# to c++ myself with Visual Studio

> In fact, it doesn't even display all of the overloads.

All you need to do to display overloads should be to type the first parenthesis as if you were calling the method and it should display the overloads.